# Broken Update Manager in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

My taskbar has this notification from Update Manager which says, "A problem occurred when checking for the updates".

I used `sudo apt-get update` but the output is this:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Hit:4 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Hit:9 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Hit:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Get:13 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease [6,739 B]                                                                                                                                                                                         
Get:14 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [1,559 B]                                                                                                                                           
Hit:15 https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:16 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                        
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                            
Hit:17 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease                                                             
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Err:13 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease               
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FEEA9169307EA071 NO_PUBKEY 8B57C5C2836F4BEB
Err:14 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG DFA175A75104960E Emulators OBS Project <Emulators@build.opensuse.org>
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunderme/texstudio/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yg-jensge/shotwell/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Reading package lists... Done                      
W: GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FEEA9169307EA071 NO_PUBKEY 8B57C5C2836F4BEB
E: The repository 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG DFA175A75104960E Emulators OBS Project <Emulators@build.opensuse.org>
E: The repository 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried  the following

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean -y
```

Nothing helped. I cannot open my "Update Manager" as well. It does not open. Here are some relevant outputs.

```
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
audio-recorder-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list       libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list                          obs.list                                    teams.list                                           vlijm-ubuntu-takeabreak-bionic.list
audio-recorder-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save  libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save                     obs.list.save                               teams.list.save                                      vlijm-ubuntu-takeabreak-bionic.list.save
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list           maarten-baert-ubuntu-simplescreenrecorder-bionic.list       signal-xenial.list                          teamviewer.list                                      vscode.list
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save      maarten-baert-ubuntu-simplescreenrecorder-bionic.list.save  signal-xenial.list.save                     teamviewer.list.save                                 vscode.list.save
google-chrome.list                          mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-bionic.list                      slack.list                                  ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-audacity-bionic.list          webupd8team-ubuntu-java-bionic.list
google-chrome.list.save                     mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-bionic.list.save                 slack.list.save                             ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-audacity-bionic.list.save     webupd8team-ubuntu-java-bionic.list.save
google-cloud-sdk.list                       nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-bionic.list                     sunderme-ubuntu-texstudio-bionic.list       umang-ubuntu-indicator-stickynotes-bionic.list       yg-jensge-ubuntu-shotwell-bionic.list
google-cloud-sdk.list.save                  nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-bionic.list.save                sunderme-ubuntu-texstudio-bionic.list.save  umang-ubuntu-indicator-stickynotes-bionic.list.save  yg-jensge-ubuntu-shotwell-bionic.list.save
```

and

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr bionic main
# deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr bionic main

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190805)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
# deb-src https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
# deb-src http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

Please help. How to update my system successfully?

Comment: @guivercbut how do I know which ppa to remove?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to re-add GPG keys for problematic repositories by

```
cd /tmp
wget https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key

wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
sudo apt-key add apt-key.gpg

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FEEA9169307EA071
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B57C5C2836F4BEB
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DFA175A75104960E
```

and then run `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu. I read that opensuse repositories shouldn't be used for debian based systems. And I don't need Google cloud SDK now. So shouldn't I just remove these two? Is there any harm in it?

Comment: The `download.opensuse.org/repositories` is special service, it allow users to create their own repositories like PPAs on launchpad.net. So this is other package building platform. If you do not need these repositories - simple remove/comment them by console text editor or using Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) graphical application.